# create a generic function that displays an alert, and accepts as input the value that is to be displayed in the alert

Tags: javascript

Function gets called. A JavaScript function is a block of code designed to perform a particular task.

A JavaScript function is executed when "something" invokes it (calls it).

```
function displays_Five() {
  window.alert("Five");
}
function displays_Four() {
  window.alert("Four");
}
function displays_Three() {
  window.alert("Three");
}
function displays_Two() {
  window.alert("Two");
}
function displays_One() {
  window.alert("One");
}
```

Comment: You really need to read a JavaScript beginners guide

Comment: Did you just copy/paste the tutorial into the question body?

Comment: are you here to help or not

Comment: You already have several answers to your question, and several people wondering if you are just here to troll

Comment: If you have an instructor, send them a mail and explain your problem. Instructors are there to answer your questions. Or, as I said, you already have an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
window.alert("Five");
window.alert("Four");
window.alert("Three");
window.alert("Two");
window.alert("One");
```

Now if you really want to create a wrapper function:

```
function myAlert(str) {
    window.alert(str);
}
myAlert("Five");
myAlert("Four");
myAlert("Three");
myAlert("Two");
myAlert("One");
```

```js
function myAlert(str) {
        window.alert(str);
}
myAlert("Five");
myAlert("Four");
myAlert("Three");
myAlert("Two");
myAlert("One");
```

Comment: Well your original didn't answer it, but since the edit lgtm... I'll upvote to offset at least ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function showAlert(contents) {
    alert(contents);
}
```

But why not just use the alert function itself?

Answer (score 0):

simple as:

```
function displayAlert(text) {
    alert(text);
}

// Prompt from client
var input = prompt('What you want?');

// Make sure input is not empty (NULL) then display client input
if(input) displayAlert(input);

// Or display static text
displayAlert('Well Done.')
```

Comment: This might end up alerting `null`.

Comment: @Sébastien bro, no one use prompt or alert any more, be kind ;) `if(input) {...}` and everything goes fine.

Comment: Not being mean, just pointing something out. Given that the OP seems to be a beginner, they might not understand what happens when they cancel the prompt. No problem at all with your code :)